# Finding a particular word in a .asp page with php

Tags: php, search

Hi I have a code like this:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html=file_get_html('xyz.asp');
echo   $html; 

// now I need to search the entire $html page for the word "happy,"

?>
```

How do it go about doing it?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? A simple `false !== strpos($html, 'happy')` check would tell you if it's in the HTML at all

Comment: Thank you for your reply.What I like to do is to find out how many occurrences a word has on a page and put them in mySQL DB

Comment: See the manual: [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)